# Something wrong with XML Schema <xs:redefine>

Tags: xml, schema

I want to redefine some complex types from an existing schema file. When I'm using  the Altova XMLSpy reported an error. It shows:

> Redefining type definition 'Address' must be an extension or restriction of itself.
>       Error location: xs:schema / xs:redefine / xs:complexType / xs:complexContent / xs:extension / @base
>       Details
>           src-redefine.5: Redefining type definition 'Address' must be an extension or restriction of itself.

And the source code has already have a `<xs:extension>` part in it.

```
<xs:redefine schemaLocation="reusable.xsd">
  <xs:complexType name="Address">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension  base="Address">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="PostCode"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:redefine>
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with it. Here's the source code of my schema files.

**Source.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="we:love:xml:schemas:but:we:hate:namespaces">
  <xs:redefine schemaLocation="reusable.xsd">
    <xs:complexType name="Address">
      <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="Address">
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="PostCode" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:redefine>
  <xs:element name="resume">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Comment describing your root element</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Thanks in advance.

**reusable.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xf="we:love:xml:schemas:but:we:hate:namespaces" targetNamespace="we:love:xml:schemas:but:we:hate:namespaces" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:complexType name="Address">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>This is a type meant to represent a generic address. It consists of an
                unlimited number of street addresses, a city, state or province, a postal code, and
                country. It is suggested that if need be, on a transform use conditional processing
                based on the Country element to get country specific layouts of the
            addresses.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="StreetAddress" type="xs:string" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="City"/>
            <xs:element name="StateOrProvince" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="PostalCode" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Country" type="xf:CountryType"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your choice of namespace URI says it all. You don't want to extend "Address", you want to extend "wlxsbwhns:Address", where the prefix wlxsbwhns is bound to your target namespace URI.